# is iterable object a copy of original object?

Tags: python, iterator

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5]

it = iter(nums)

print(next(it))

print(next(it))

for i in nums:
   print(i)

here the result is:
1
2
1
2
3
4
5
```

So my question is that when we apply iter method on a object then does it create a copy of object on which it runs next method?

Comment: it returns an `iter`ator over the original object. see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iter(object)` returns an *iterator object* which is an iterator version of the object given to it given that it implements `__iter__`. `iter(object)` doesn't create a copy of the object.

```
>>> l=[[1,2],[4,5]]
>>> it=iter(l)
>>>next(it).append(3) #appending to the output of next() mutates the list l
>>> l
[[1,2,3],[4,5]]
>>> next(it).append(6)
>>> l
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> it=iter(l)
>>> l.pop() #Mutating the list l mutated iterator it.
[4,5,6]
>>>list(it)
[[1,2,3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The **`=`** operator assigns values from right side operands to left side operands" i.e. `c = a + b` assigns value of `a + b` into `c` [Operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm)

You're not altering any variables present in the right side of an assignment line, a copy of the value is having a function applied to it and then that result is being assigned the new variable name **`it`**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to figure it out:

```
lst = ['Hi', 'I am a copy!']
itr = iter(lst)
print(next(itr))
lst[1] = 'I am _not_ a copy!'
print(next(itr))
```

(`iter(lst)` does not create a copy of `lst`)

Answer (score 0):

No, they don't. Some Python types, e.g. all its collections, just support being iterated over multiple times. Multiple iterator objects can hold references to the very same list, they all just maintain their own position within the list.

Notice some effects:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
it = iter(lst)
lst.pop()  # modify the original list

list(it)  # the iterator is affected
# [1,2,3,4]
```

Even more obvious is the case of exhaustable iterators and calling `iter` on them:

```
it1 = iter(range(10))
it2 = iter(it1)
next(it)
# 0
next(it2)
# 1
next(it)
# 2
next(it2)
# 3
```

Clearly the iterators share state.

Comment: "the iterators" and "share" is misleading. They're both the same single iterator (as `it2 is it1` would show). (Btw it should be `next(it1)` instead of `next(it)`.